# Combining two tables with a PIVOT statement - SQL Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table like this called DWH_DATA:

```
DATETIME         FK_FEDERAL_STATE     FK_ACCOMODATION   ARRIVALS   NIGHTS
--------------- --------------------  --------------- ----------  ----------
200010               W96-7              61              2433       16111
200011               W96-9              86              3718       30319
200012               W96-3              87              1100        8487
200101               W96-2              998             239         1038
```

Additional info Datetime = first four number = year + last two numbers = month

Then I have a table DWH_FEDERAL_STATES:

```
CODE(PK)         NAME                   
---------- -------------------
 W96-2      Country 2
 W96-3      Country 3              
 W96-9      Country 9    
 W96-7      Country 7
```

Now I would like to get all  nights for each federal state. Result should look like this:

```
       Country 2  Country 3  Country 9  Country 7
200010    6979                              16111
200011    ..
200012    ..
200101    ..
```

What I've already tried is a PIVOT Statement:

```
  SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        DATETIME, 
        NIGHTS,
        dwh_data.fk_federal_state As federalState
    FROM 
        dwh_data JOIN DWH_FEDERAL_STATES
         ON dwh_data.fk_federal_state = dwh_federal_states.code
) t 
PIVOT(
    COUNT(federalState) 
    FOR federalState IN ('Country 2','Country 3','Country 9')
      
       
) ORDER BY 1;
```

The result I get with mine is:

```
DATETIME                 NIGHTS 'Country 2' 'Country 3' 'Country 9'
-------------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
197707                    83648           0           0           0
197707                    87301           0           0           0
197707                    97350           0           0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `COUNT`, you want to `SUM` the nights and use the `name` column:

```sql
SELECT datetime,
       COALESCE(country_2, 0) AS country_2,
       COALESCE(country_3, 0) AS country_3,
       COALESCE(country_9, 0) AS country_9
FROM   (
  SELECT d.DATETIME,
         nights,
         f.name
  FROM   dwh_data d
         JOIN DWH_FEDERAL_STATES f
         ON d.fk_federal_state = f.code
)
PIVOT(
  SUM(nights) 
  FOR name IN (
    'Country 2' AS country_2,
    'Country 3' AS country_3,
    'Country 9' AS country_9
  )
)
ORDER BY
       datetime;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dwh_data (DATETIME, FK_FEDERAL_STATE, FK_ACCOMODATION, ARRIVALS, NIGHTS) AS
SELECT 200010, 'W96-7',  61, 2433, 16111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200011, 'W96-9',  86, 3718, 30319 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200012, 'W96-3',  87, 1100,  8487 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200101, 'W96-2', 998,  239,  1038 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE DWH_FEDERAL_STATES (CODE, NAME) AS
SELECT 'W96-2', 'Country 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W96-3', 'Country 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL              
SELECT 'W96-9', 'Country 9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W96-7', 'Country 7' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATETIME | COUNTRY_2 | COUNTRY_3 | COUNTRY_9 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 200010 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | 200011 | 0 | 0 | 30319 |
> | 200012 | 0 | 8487 | 0 |
> | 200101 | 1038 | 0 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb1d25efc8af26128a7da50e584abfe6)*

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but the values in the country columns is 0 everywhere

Comment: in the country columns there should be the nights

Comment: @saja Added a db<>fiddle. and not everything is `0`. You need to debug and work out what is different between the fiddle and your code.

Comment: yeah but the values are not correct. So not everything is 0 but everything is wrong

Comment: @saja Why were you using `COUNT` in your query? You don't want to count rows. Updated to use `SUM`.

Comment: Any reason why there are only 0 in the table on my side

Comment: in your db fiddle you use Oracle 18c. On my machine I use oracle 11g. Is that maybe the reason why it's not working?

Comment: @saja If your `name` columns have different values (i.e. different capitalisation or spelling) or are in a `CHAR` column and have trailing spaces then it won't match. You need to debug it and work out what is different. Oracle 11g supports pivot with the same syntax so there should not be a version issue.